# Group dictionary by multiple properties of key

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, grouping

I have a following code, which groups list by three properties of its elements and returns list of lists:

```
List<Employee> data;
var groups = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.Company, x.Position, x.Age })
                 .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                 .ToList();
```

Cannot comprehend to change this code to work with dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Employee, Report> data;
```

I need to create a list of dictionaries grouped by these three properties of dictionary key.

Comment: what if get list<Employee> from dictionary and do same ? f.e data.Keys.GroupBy(x => new { x.Company, x.Position, x.Age })
                 .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                 .ToList();

Comment: @Z.R.T. answer it up

Comment: @Z.R.T. Unfortunately, grouping the keys only we lose the values. This code returns List<List<Employee>>. It does not keep Report for the Employee.

Comment: What is `Report`? You should provide a definition of your `Employee` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least 2 options to do that:

**First:** Use groupping on your dictionary's Key properties and then project dictionary's Values to Groups:

```
    Dictionary<Employee, Report> data;
    var groups = data
                 .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.Company, x.Key.Position, x.Key.Age }, pair => pair.Value)
                 .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                 .ToList();
```

**Second:** as @Z.R.T. said, you can project only Values of the dictionary first and than group:

```
    Dictionary<Employee, Report> data;
    var groups = data
                 .Select(pair => pair.Key)
                 .GroupBy(x => new { x.Company, x.Position, x.Age }, pair => pair.Value)
                 .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                 .ToList();
```

**UPD**

However if you need to preserve relation Employee -> Report, you can just group by its Key:

```
    Dictionary<Employee, Report> data;
    List<List<KeyValuePair<Employee , Report>>> groups = data
                 .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.Company, x.Key.Position, x.Key.Age })
                 .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: The third variant is exactly what I need. Thank you!